# Downloading a 50 MB file from SQL Server in ASP.NET stops in middle for a while

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

When I'm trying to download a 50 MB file from a database (it is not an issue with a smaller file size), it stops in the middle sometimes and resumes again after a long time. Am I mssing something?

The code,

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DownloadFile", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);

    try
    {
        conPortal.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        // File name
        string fileName = reader.GetString(0);

        // Total bytes to read
        int dataToRead = reader.GetInt32(1);

        Context.Server.ScriptTimeout = 600;
        Context.Response.Buffer = true;
        Context.Response.Clear();

        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                                   "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\";");

        Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataToRead.ToString());

        int ChunkSize = 262144;

        // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[ChunkSize];
        long offset = 0;
        long length;

        // Read the bytes.
        while (dataToRead > 0)
        {
            // Verify that the client is connected.
            if (Context.Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                // Read the data in buffer
                length = reader.GetBytes(2, offset, buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
                offset += ChunkSize;

                // Write the data to the current output stream.
                Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, (int) length);

                // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                Context.Response.Flush();

                buffer = new Byte[ChunkSize];
                dataToRead = dataToRead - (int) length;
            }
            else
            {
                //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                dataToRead = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you're using a manual try/finally for disposal rather than a using statement? Are you sure that the block is fetching rather than writing out the data to the client? Why are you increasing `offset` by `ChunkSize` rather than `length`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int ChunkSize = 262144;
```

There you go, that's 25 MB - right in the middle of a 50 MB download.  Try modifying this and see what happens. Any reason you set it to that particular value?

Comment: Exactly .WAY too big chunk size. YOu should go for something snmall (4 mb or so). ALso flush async. THis way you flush one slice WHILE loading the next one from the database.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have played with the chunk sizes. If small like 1024, start download time is extremely quick, but entire download time is very long and it knocks down the whole server. If large, start download time is quite long (user might think nothing is happening), but it downloads little faster after that.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you stream content from a SQL Server query result. You **must** specify [`CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx):

> Provides a way for the DataReader to
>   handle rows that contain columns with
>   large binary values. Rather than
>   loading the entire row,
>   SequentialAccess enables the
>   DataReader to load data as a stream.
>   You can then use the GetBytes or
>   GetChars method to specify a byte
>   location to start the read operation,
>   and a limited buffer size for the data
>   being returned.

And, as others have pointed out, 25MB is not a reasonable buffer chunk size. Try something like 4K (typical [TDS packet size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174503%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)) or 16k (typical SSL frame size if connection is encrypted).